# Path of a ball moving horizontally

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to simulate a ball moving horizontally.

I took speed to be `v = 3, t = 1.5, distance = 4.5`. Firstly, I want a static plot of the ball moving horizontally. I also kept `s''[t] == 0` in the following code as horizontal acceleration should be 0.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
v = 3; 
Subscript[t, max] = 1.5;
f = 
  NDSolve[
   {s''[t] == 0, s[t] == distance, s'[t] == 3, 
    WhenEvent[s[t] == 0, s'[t] -> -0.32 s'[t]]}, 
   s[t], {t, 0, 1.5}]
```

For some reason, this can't be solved as I am getting the feedback that a list of equations is expected instead of true in the first argument. I am not sure what went wrong.

To plot the ball I did:

```
ball[t_] := s[t] /. f[[1]];
Plot[ball[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

However, I can't plot or animate this if I don't get a proper solution with `NDSolve`.

Comment: This is a simple kinematic problem and doesn't need `NDSolve`. But it does need a consistent set of initial/final conditions, and the ones you give are not consistent. So your problem is bad physics and not Mathematica.

Comment: The problem I attempted just gave me the velocity (v=3) and the fact that the ball is moving horizontally (suppose on a table or through a tube) and then it falls on the ground and bounces off. My goal is to visualize its movement on mathematica. I simply assumed time and distance which I did not have in the question originally. same goes for the initial conditions and i never really studied physics so i had to rely on assumptions.

Comment: Then you need parameters that describe the height of the table or tube above the floor and how much velocity is lost on the bounce, but the  problem still does not require solving differential equations, just a  little algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be simulated using NDSolve. When rolling on the table, the vertical (y) acceleration and velocity is zero and the x velocity is constant. When the ball comes to the end of the table, the y acceleration is negative g (for gravitation). This is enforced by the first WhenEvent. When the ball hits the ground, the y velocity is negated with a loss factor. This is enforced by the second WhenEvent. We include the y acceleration ay[t] as a first order diffeq because we need to change its value.

```
(* constants *)
tableLength = 3; tableHeight = 2;
vx0 = 1; x0 = 0; vy0 = 0; y0 = tableHeight;
g = 1;
bounceLoss = .9;
tMax = 20;

(* equations of motion *)
eqs = {
    (* start out rolling on table *)
   x''[t] == 0, x'[0] == vx0, x[0] == x0,
    (* vertical motion *)
   y''[t] == ay[t], y'[0] == vy0, y[0] == y0,
   (* vertical acceleration is time dependent *)
   ay'[t] == 0, ay[0] == 0,
   (* fall off table *)
   WhenEvent[x[t] > tableLength, ay[t] -> -g],
   (* hit the ground and bounce with loss *)
   WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, {y'[t] -> -bounceLoss y'[t]}]
   };

sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tMax}];

plot = ParametricPlot[sol, {t, 0, tMax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Altitude"}, AspectRatio -> .3]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't g=-9.81 ms^-2? Though I've noticed that the motion of the ball is much less distinct with g=-9.81 and more noticeable with g=1? Is there a particular reason for taking this value of g?

Comment: I just chose numbers that made a nice graph. For a real world solution you should of course use the acceleration of gravity for your particular planet. 